# Joining three tables in one query

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables:

violation: violation_id,violation_name

violators: violator_id, violation_id

previous_violator: prev_violator_id, violator_id,violation_id

I want to display the violator name and its violation from violators table and previous_violator table.

I tried this code:

```
SELECT violation_name 
FROM (SELECT violation_name FROM violators  
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT prev_violator_id
      FROM previous_violator
        LEFT JOIN violators ON violators.violator_id = previous_violator.violator_id) tmp
INNER JOIN violation ON tmp.violation_id = violation.violation_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: SELECT v.violation_name, pv.prev_violator_id FROM violation AS v INNER JOIN violators AS vr ON (v.violation_id = vr.violation_id) INNER JOIN previous_violator AS pv ON (v.violation_id = pv.violation_id)

Comment: Why do you have separate violators and previous_violator tables?

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images). [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE to make the query easier, but as mentioned in the comment, there is not reason for prev_violator and violator to be in different tables. so when the data is migrated and corrected, you can replace the CTE with the new table

```
with all_violators as (
    select 0 violator, 1 violator_id , null prev_violator_id  -- from violators 
    union all 
    select 0 violator, 1 violator_id , 1 prev_violator_id -- from prev_violators
)

select violation_name, violator_id from violation v join all_violators a on a.violator_id = v.violation_id
```